# how to merge array of images which are generated by for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of 5 images and I must resize them all in (16,16) dimension. Then, I have to print each image as a column vector.

For this, I use a `for` loop to resize all the images but I can't merge them in an array. What should I do if I want to print 5 column matrix of 5 images side by side as a (256*5) dimension matrix ?

Next, I provide the code I have done so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import itertools
import xlsxwriter

folder="E:/DOCUMENT(M.TECHS)/New folder/word/*.png"
files = list(glob.glob (folder))

i=0
for i in files:
    abc=cv2.imread(i,0)
    d=(16,16)
    abc1=cv2.resize(abc,d,interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    r,c=abc1.shape
    width, height = abc1.shape
    arr = np.ravel(abc1)
    print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending all images to an array then join them using [np.concatenate(.., axis=1)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). For example, change as follows:

```
imgs = []

for i in files:
    abc=cv2.imread(i,0)
    d=(16,16)
    abc1=cv2.resize(abc,d,interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    r,c=abc1.shape
    width, height = abc1.shape
    arr = np.ravel(abc1)
    imgs.append(arr) 

final_img = np.concatenate(imgs, axis=1)
```